# Some meshes that have textures import just fine but others come in all solid pink

Tags: modeling

When I import my meshes with textures some import just fine, but others,  just come in all solid pink.

I tried saving all the textures then importing but all my models but they just become solid pink.

Even the armatures don't load right

[image: glitch?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pink textures are because there is no file at the path where the texture is loaded.

Switch to the Image Editor and view the image that doesn't work. Press `N` (or select View > Sidebar in the menu) to open the sidebar and pick the "Image" tab. You should be able to see the path plus a "Can't Load Image" message.

[image: Image Editor showing "Can't Load Image"]

Either click the folder icon to browse for the image you want, or put the image file you want at the location shown in the path and hit the reload icon.